# Can't Drop SQL Database After Exception During Insert Statement

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I'm running into an issue with an application I'm working on. Here is a breakdown of what is happening.

1. Create new database via code (succeeds)
2. Connect to newly created database and create tables (succeeds too)
3. Inserting data into previously created tables (this fails with an **exception**)
4. Show error message to the user
5. Open a new connection on the **master** database
6. Delete database created in step 1

Step 6 fails due to a:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot drop database "ImportFail" because it is currently in use.

The error message kinda makes sense if you have unclosed connections or use a connection on the database you want to drop but from what I can see that is not the case.

I went into SQL Server Management Studio and looked at what is blocking the drop statement. Spid 52 seems to be blocked by 53. 53 however is the DDL statement that is creating the database in step 1 - which undoubtedly succeeds.

[image]

The creation of the database and the subsequent insert statements (or any `SqlCommand` in our codebase) is going through the following method. I can't see why any connection would be lingering around here even in case of an exception.

[image]

Comment: Try adding `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();` after the exception.

Comment: Hi @DanGuzman - Just tried it and it worked, thanks for that :D Wanna write this as an answer so I can award you?

Comment: @Codexer - It's not. As mentioned above, every query or command goes through an intermediate layer which manages the lifecycle of the connection/commands. See image above. Also, calling ClearAllPools made it work immediately.

Comment: What happens if, before you drop, you run the command `ALTER DATABASE ImportFail SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();` after the exception. This static method will physically close and remove pooled connections holding a shared lock due on the database that prevents the database from being dropped.

Note that closing/disposing connections only returns the connection to the pool and is not enough alone.